# Show query result for each table field as separate records

Tags: sql, sqlite

I got a table called `tblWord` in a `SQLite` database like this.

```
|IdWord | Word |   One  |    Two   |  Three  | Four   |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  1    | Alex | I Alex | You Alex | He Alex |She Alex|
```

*Of course this sample is a concept, trying to simplify the question.*

I'm trying to search for `Alex` in database in a way I get a separate result record for each field. The result should be like this

```
|IdWord | Word |   One  |    Two   |  Three  | Four   |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  1    | Alex | I Alex |   null   |   null  |  null  |
|  1    | Alex |  null  | You Alex |   null  |  null  |
|  1    | Alex |  null  |   null   | He Alex |  null  |
|  1    | Alex |  null  |   null   |   null  |She Alex|
```

I tried this query as it somehow has worked before in the almost same situations.

```
SELECT mw.IdWord, mw.IdType, mw.Word, qw.One, iw.Two, sw.Three, pw.Four
FROM   tblWord AS mw LEFT OUTER JOIN
       tblWord AS qw ON mw.IdWord = qw.IdWord LEFT OUTER JOIN
       tblWord AS iw ON mw.IdWord = iw.IdWord LEFT OUTER JOIN
       tblWord AS sw ON mw.IdWord = sw.IdWord LEFT OUTER JOIN
       tblWord AS pw ON mw.IdWord = pw.IdWord
WHERE  (qw.One LIKE '%Alex%') OR
       (iw.Two LIKE '%Alex%') OR
       (sw.Three LIKE '%Alex%') OR
       (pw.Four LIKE '%Alex%')
```

But in this case, it just shows the results like this:

```
|IdWord | Word |   One  |    Two   |  Three  | Four   |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  1    | Alex | I Alex | You Alex | He Alex |She Alex|
```

Is there anyway to get the result, the way I'm looking for?

Comment: Not sure I understand... Can you give an example input/output? Why not simply `SELECT IdWord, IdType, Word, One, Two, Three, Four FROM tblWord WHERE One LIKE '%ALEX%' OR Two LIKE '%ALEX%' OR Three LIKE '%ALEX%' OR Four LIKE '%ALEX%';`? EDIT: Ah, is that a single row Alex and you're wanting that output once per match in One, Two, Three, or Four?

Comment: @Luke Yes. I want the single row Alex to appear 4 times

Comment: Would `(SELECT etc FROM tblWord WHERE One LIKE '%ALEX%') UNION ALL (SELECT etc WHERE Two LIKE etc) UNION ALL etc` work?

Comment: @Luke Yes! it works. Only you missed the second `From tblWord` :)

Comment: There's an `etc` there! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use unions like this:

```
select idword, word, one, null as two, null as three, null as four
from table1 
where one like '%Alex%'
UNION
select idword, word, null as one, two, null as three, null as four
from table1 
where two like '%Alex%'
UNION
select idword, word, null as one, null as two, three, null as four
from table1 
where three like '%Alex%'
UNION
select idword, word, null as one, null as two, null as three, four
from table1 
where four like '%Alex%'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d03be/4

Comment: Thank you! it works in `SQLite` (but not in `SqlCe`)

Answer (score 0):

Not too keen on sqlite, but this code produces the output you desire:

```
with cte as (
    SELECT IdWord, Word, One, null as Two, null as Three, null as Four FROM tblWord WHERE One LIKE '%ALEX%'
    union
    SELECT IdWord, Word, null as One, Two, null as Three, null as Four FROM tblWord WHERE One LIKE '%ALEX%'
    union
    SELECT IdWord, Word, null as One, null as Two, Three, null as Four FROM tblWord WHERE One LIKE '%ALEX%'
    union
    SELECT IdWord, Word, null as One, null as Two, null as Three, Four FROM tblWord WHERE One LIKE '%ALEX%'),
     cte2 as (
     select IdWord, Word, One, Two, Three, Four, ROW_NUMBER() 
     OVER (PARTITION BY IdWord order by (select 0)) as RowNumber
     from cte
    )
    select IdWord, Word, One, Two, Three, Four from cte2 order by RowNumber desc
```

Results:

```
IdWord  Word    One Two Three   Four
1   Alex    I Alex  NULL    NULL    NULL
1   Alex    NULL    You Alex    NULL    NULL
1   Alex    NULL    NULL    She Alex    NULL
1   Alex    NULL    NULL    NULL    He Alex
```